# Frontend sending only OPTIONS request

Tags: django, angular, nginx, uwsgi

I have a question about OPTIONS request.
I have an application, with Angular2 on frontend and Nginx-uWSGI-Django backend. All parts of app are working fine, except for Angular Datatables. Frontend and backend are on the same domain but different subdomains, but as I understood that is no CORS used. Except for Datatables, at that time Angular sending OPTIONS request, and after server answers with 200, no GET request is sended. Just OPTIONS and nothing else. How it can be solved, or what problem can cause it? Thanks a lot.

 P.S. I have Access-Allow-Origin header "turned on" and on local machine with django dev-server all working fine.

Comment: Have you checked your browser console for errors?

Comment: Yep, and it actually logged : "Cross-Origin Request Blocked" for datatable request. And rest of is was : "Reason: missing token ‘x-requested-with’ in CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight channel". In response I have "Access-Control-Allow-Headers : origin" and I think that is a problem. Rest of requests are not sending with "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest", but only datatable do. Rest of responses have "Access-Control-Allow-Headers : *". But I don't understand how to fix this.

Comment: So you can either remove the x-requested-with header from the requests or to include it in the list of allowed headers ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’. But I have no experience with Django so I cannot help you with it.