# only OPTIONS request is sent with a 200 response

Tags: django, angular

My situation is a bit similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43519464/frontend-sending-only-options-request) but it differs a bit nor there is an answer.

My backend is python and front-end is Angular. Live sever is Ngnix/Unix while dev is Windows. Every request just sends OPTIONS request, with successful response of 200 but then GET/POST are not followed. It was working perfectly fine and only on production sever is it not working. There are no CORS errors in the console and backend is debug= True for checking purposes but not problems so far cos obviously no get/post is being made.

On development machine, all is working. Previous team had added a custom header 'language':

```
const clonedRequest = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Language', lang) });
```

which I noticed is never sent when connected to the live one. In the development setup, I see the following headers:

```
Accept application/json
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection keep-alive
Content-Length 21
Content-Type application/json
Host 127.0.0.1:9000
Language en
Origin http://localhost:4800

Referer http://localhost:4800/start/forgot-pwd
```

When connecting to the production from front end (Development or in production), the Language header is not being sent but I doubt it has issues. Regardless, my CORS on the backend looks like this:

```
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
    'accept',
    'accept-encoding',
    'authorization',
    'content-type',
    'dnt',
    'origin',
    'user-agent',
    'language',
    'x-requested-with',
)
```

Comment: A temporary solution is to bypass CORS as it won't come in production. This can be done with the help of a [plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi).

Comment: Thanks @Arcteezy. It worked. Seems like I have to change something on the backend CORS which was woking just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to whitelist specific origins.
Using [corsheaders](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers) such as:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    'localhost:4800',
    '127.0.0.1:4800'
]
```

You also need to add to you middlewares right after `SecurityMiddleware`

```
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
```

And you also need to add `'corsheaders',` to you `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Furthermore, you can simply have `CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True` set and in addition to what I listed above to have CORS working.

Comment: thanks @tgdn. I actually have whitelist and middlewhee as well as INSTALLED_APPS set. I believe the browser would have complained if it was a CORS issue, right? At least it used to do on the very first deployment.